# Redirect asmx to aspx page

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, asmx

I have an asmx page with a sample function in a project. Now I want to redirect to the AgentPage.aspx page when I am calling this service. I put a break point in my local project, but the event did not fire.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string EchoInput(String input)
    {
        // Method code goes here.
        string url = "http://localhost:33973/Agents/AgentPage.aspx?"+input;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);            
    }
```

Comment: try `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("url");`

Comment: I got the error unable to evaluate expression ..

Comment: I dont think this would ever work. asmx aka web service are meant to be accessed using XMLHTTP request from client or using WebRequest from web server(May be I never came across such requirement where we need to redirect the user to a ASPX page). The best thing you can do is write a URL to the response and ask the client browser to redirect to the specified link. If its the server code you can use Response.Redirect in the callback method.

Comment: Can you give me a sample

Answer (score 1):

Its interesting , what actually is the requirement.you are mixing two things here. may be what you can do is return the url which you want to redirect to and the caller can go to the page. If you do a response.redirect it will not comply with contract of return type as string

Comment: I have a console application and a web application. Web having a asmx page. I added that reference in console project and call asmx function from console. Its working fine. If a request enter into asmx page i would like to redirect to a web application page.

Comment: You should do the redirect from your web application rather than asmx.